# azure data sync for temporal table

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azure-data-sync

Is it possible to synchronize temporal table data with the main table using Azure Data Sync? I couldn't locate a comprehensive official documentation on this.Can anyone please help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporal tables are not supported with SQL Data Sync as described on [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-data-sync-data-sql-server-sql-database?view=azuresql#unsupported-column-types).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. According to the documentation, it's stated that System-generated columns for temporal tables are not permitted. However, I haven't come across any information explicitly stating that Temporal tables are unsupported. This has left me a bit puzzled. Could you please clarify?

Comment: You are always welcome. If you try to sync a temporal table, on the provisoning you will get  on the hub database the error: "Database provisioning failed with the exception "Cannot insert an explicit value into a GENERATED ALWAYS column in table" and  SqlError Number:13536. On the member database you may get  Error Code: -2146232060 - and SqlError Number:156, As result do no sync temporal tables with SQL Data Sync.

Comment: Temporal tables are system-versioned tables,